# Weird behaviour in jscrollpane with scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

`api.scrollToY` function is running recursively in scroll event only , is there any way to stop it?

```
 $('.scroll-pane').bind('scroll',function (e) { 
      api.scrollToY(100)
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: Why do you need to scroll when a user scrolls? You are avoiding users to scroll along the page.

Comment: because i have to reinitilize the scroll-y position

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, but if you need to listen an event like scroll or resize (that fires tons of times) you can use a debouncer for your function. Underscore library have one very useful. See more:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

You can modify easy to change `resize` to `scroll`

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('scroll', myEfficientFn);
```

Comment: i'm using jscrollpane plugin

Comment: It doesn't matter. My answer is to avoid tons of firing events in `resize` and `scroll` events. Explain better your question if this is not that you need. It's hard to understand what you need and why you need the piece of code that you share. If the question was better explained, now you've got various answers.